# Impossible things with clone of TFS

Tags: tfs

We created a copy of our production TFS to test various applications we build internally for our needs. Thus, we created a fresh install of TFS and attached old databases to it.

However, I noticed one strange thing: when I change a WI on our production TFS the change gets reflected on our copy, and vise versa. We do not have notifications between two TFS instances.

How it is possible?

Comment: Are the databases on different servers, or is it one server with both databases?

Comment: Yes, two different servers, different databases.

Answer (score 0):

We have done the same in the past and it seems that along with the old databases a whole bunch of garbage came along to the new server and some connections exist between the two although we did not create them. So be very careful what you bring in the new server and don't just copy the databases, take only what you need or things will get wild :)